# How to get a directory path from the client using html form

Tags: html

I am developing some web app to be used on my local pc only.

The question is that I want to be able to browse to some directory or file and get its path. So is this possible using some file/directory path picker (not the whole dir, just its path).
I don't want to manually type the path in the text input, rather to have some visualized way to navigate to the dir.

Thanks

Comment: If I got what you want to do right, JS doesn't have folder picker dialog! But you can select a file in that folder and get the path of the file, it's possible with file API of HTML5.

Answer (score -1):

Previous Removed

EDITED:

```
$("#someFileUpload").change(InputChanged);
function InputChanged(e){
    var fileList = e.target.files;
    //You now have a list of the files uploaded, from here you can work with the objects..
}
```

Comment: Well, this looks like a lot of stuff to understand:) isn't there some simpler solution ?

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba please don't use this code as anything other than an example of terrible code.

Comment: @Dancrumb just an example I've found that can give someone an idea of where to start.  Also, don't say "it sucks, don't do that", provide some form of feedback on what the best practice is;tldr: Back your claims.

Comment: [Why not to use `Function`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope).
[Why not to use `with`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/with). Both from MDN, recommending against their usage. In addition, the symbolic soup in the assignment of `fn` is unnecessarily convoluted. Finally, the function `tmpl` is declared inside an immediate function which is normally used to keep the global namespace clean, but then explicitly pollutes it.

Comment: All of these are major problems... I'm not blaming you for writing the code, but it's important for programmers to recognise the pretty serious failings of this code.

Comment: @Dancrumb You're right, I should have cropped out the section that he/she needed instead of being lazy and posting the whole thing.

Comment: @LoaiGhoraba I have stripped my answer down to the basics of what you are looking for.  I hope this helps...

Comment: Seems it there is a security issue in the browsers that prevents getting the file path, it just returns c:fakepath/.

Thanks guys :)